# Invoke Batch file using Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, batch-file, azure-sql-database, sql-data-warehouse

I am trying to run

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'c:\test.bat'
```

in SQL Azure Data Warehouse but I found out that xp_CMDShell  is not supported in Azure, can you help with an alternative to invoke an exe from Azure Data warehouse?

Within the batch file I intend to copy a CSV from one location to another but this should happen after my condition is evaluated as true in the stored proc logic. This logic sits in the middle of stored proc code and hence I dont wan't this to be an independent activity(don't want an Azure Batch job or time trigger)